# Is Dependency Injection a good idea when not all instances are used?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm a supporter of using Dependency Injection on your application, despite some people consider it add unnecessary complexity to the code. 
In the past days I've wondered that, for some scenarios, there may be some waste when using DI.

Let me explain it with code examples:

Using DI

```
public class Class 
{
    private Service1 service1;
    private Service2 service2;

    public MyClass (Service1 service1, Service2 service2) 
    {
        this.service1 = service1;
        this.service2 = service2;
    }

    private int SampleMethod() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("doing something with service 1");
        service1.DoSomething();
        return 0;
    }

    private int SampleMethod2() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("doing something with service 2");
        service2.DoSomethingElse();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What if I rarely call SampleMethod2 and I will be injecting it every single time a Class instance is needed? 
Wouldn't that be wasting resources?

I got this question a few days ago and I'm trying to figure out the response. Is it easier not using DI and let every method to create the instance they need when they get used in order to avoid this "waste"?

Is this a justified "waste" thanks to the decoupling that DI provides?

Comment: Dependency Injection is not "creating instances" thats up to your IoC container.  You can scope those instances to limit how many or how often they are created (the exact options are up to which IoC container you use).  Dependency injection is a pattern and should _always_ be used no matter how often the dependency is called.

Comment: You can create overloaded constructors that take 0 or 1 arguments. You could also add overloads of your `SampleMethod` that take a `Service1` argument.

Comment: It is waste, of course. As solution - just split methods by interfaces and inject only interfaces - you can split class later or leave it be for whatever reason you have. DI is concept which is pretty flexible if you are working with interfaces instead of concrete classes. I have never encountered a problem where Im unable to refactor or test something or simplify dependencies if it is correctly hidden behind interfaces.

Comment: @maccettura "Dependency injection is a pattern and should always be used". While I'll agree about dependency injection; not every pattern is applicable to every situation. Perhaps "Dependency Injection is a best practice" would be less confusing to those who don't understand that :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah, I agree your wording is better.  I cant edit my comment as its been too long but Ill upvote yours!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it will be "wasted", but the nature of that waste depends on how its set up:

- If `Service2` is always created as a new instance; that's fairly expensive
- If `Service2` is in single instance mode, all its doing is fetching an existing instance (super cheap)
- If `Class` is in single instance mode; its fetching *that* instance and not injecting anything new

Moreover, this would suggest a violation of SRP. Perhaps `Class` should be split into two objects, one that depends on `Service1` and one that depends on `Service 2` (or even both).

Regardless of the above, the "waste" is only important if it actually impacts your application, the benefits of DI vastly outweigh these kinds of problems.